# how can I paginate images from database using PHP?

Tags: php, pagination

I've got this pagination code:

```
<?php
        $db_username = 'root'; // Your MYSQL Username.
        $db_password = ''; // Your MYSQL Password.
        $db_name = 'database_name_here'; // Your Database name.
        $db_host = 'localhost';

        $conDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('Error: Could not connect to database.');

        // Pagination Function
        function pagination($query,$per_page=10,$page=1,$url='?'){   
            global $conDB; 
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conDB,$query));
            $total = $row['num'];
            $adjacents = "2"; 

            $prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
            $nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
            $lastlabel = "Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;";

            $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
            $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

            $prev = $page - 1;                          
            $next = $page + 1;

            $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);

            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; // //last page minus 1

            $pagination = "";
            if($lastpage > 1){   
                $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='page_info'>Page {$page} of {$lastpage}</li>";

                    if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$prev}'>{$prevlabel}</a></li>";

                if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){   
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++){
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
                    }

                } elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)){

                    if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {

                        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++){
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
                        }
                        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>";  

                    } elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {

                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
                        }
                        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>";      

                    } else {

                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>{$counter}</a></li>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                    
                        }
                    }
                }

                    if ($page < $counter - 1) {
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page={$next}'>{$nextlabel}</a></li>";
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>{$lastlabel}</a></li>";
                    }

                $pagination.= "</ul>";        
            }

            return $pagination;
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pagination - OTallu.com</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        /* For this page only */
        body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
        .wrap { text-align:center; line-height:21px; padding:20px; }

        /* For pagination function. */
        ul.pagination {
            text-align:center;
            color:#829994;
        }
        ul.pagination li {
            display:inline;
            padding:0 3px;
        }
        ul.pagination a {
            color:#0d7963;
            display:inline-block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            border:1px solid #cde0dc;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.pagination a:hover,
        ul.pagination a.current {
            background:#0d7963;
            color:#fff;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="wrap">

        <?php
        $page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

        $per_page = 10; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

        $startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

        $statement = "`records` ORDER BY `id` ASC"; // Change `records` according to your table name.

        $results = mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

            // displaying records.
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo $row['name'] . '<br>';
            }

        } else {
             echo "No records are found.";
        }

         // displaying paginaiton.
        echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?');
        ?>
        </div><!-- .wrap -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

the result of this pagination code is the following picture:
[text pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTwb6.jpg)

but I want it not just show the data from database on the screen but put them in html img tags so the results can be 10 simple pictures per page, NOT the text alone. take a look at the final result I want(created in photoshop): [pagination-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKzCB.jpg)

I'm new with PHP and your help will be invaluable, THANKS.

Comment: Then whatever is outputting "dummy line" would instead output an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this statement of `while` loop, `echo $row['name'] . '<br>';`. Instead of *name*, you should fetch *image name* or complete image path(whatever is there in *that* column). Subsequently, you have to use `<img src="..." />` to display the images. So your `while` loop would be somewhat like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<img src="/path/'.$row['ImgName'].'" alt="..." height="..." width="..." />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rajdeep for your answer and the example of the code of it. It worked

Comment: @Ahmad.b1995 You're very welcome! Glad I could help. :-)